# Set multiply parameters in a for-loop

Tags: php, for-loop, parameters

I am new to PHP and I am trying to set multiple parameters to the same value.
I have done it the (probably) ugly way.

```
$thpic0 = "thpic_dummy";
$thpic1 = "thpic_dummy";
$thpic2 = "thpic_dummy";
$thpic3 = "thpic_dummy";
etc...
$thpic13 = "thpic_dummy";
$thpic14 = "thpic_dummy";
```

Since the only char changing is the last char in the parameters I thaught it could be done in a for-loop, but this (obviously) does not work:

```
//Reset th sorting pics
for($i=0;$i<=14;$i++)
{
$thpic{$i} = "thpic_dummy";
}
```

Is there another way I can do this without too many lines of code?

Comment: Why don't you use an [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Maybe it's a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @pNre He _is_ actually using an array (`{…}` is an alternative to `[…]`). (Believe me or not; test it yourself with a simple `$a = array("a"); var_dump($a{0});`)

Comment: @bwoebi yeah, sometimes php is really confusing. I guess in this case the answer is just, to access values doing `$thpic[index]` instead of `$thpicindex`.

Comment: Wow! many answers within an hour, this is the place to seek for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is `${…}` instead of `$…{…}`:

```
${"thpic$i"} = ...;
```

would be the valid syntax.

Some further PHP manual lecture about this: http://php.net/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I think `arrays` will suit better.

Comment: @u_mulder true, but that wasn't really his question…

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to probably put this into an array like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 14; $i++) {
    $thpic[$i] = "thpic_dummy";
}

print_r($thpic);
```

This returns something like this:
Array

```
(
    [0] => thpic_dummy
    [1] => thpic_dummy
    [2] => thpic_dummy
    [3] => thpic_dummy
    [4] => thpic_dummy
    [5] => thpic_dummy
    [6] => thpic_dummy
    [7] => thpic_dummy
    [8] => thpic_dummy
    [9] => thpic_dummy
    [10] => thpic_dummy
    [11] => thpic_dummy
    [12] => thpic_dummy
    [13] => thpic_dummy
    [14] => thpic_dummy
)
```

Which you could call like:

```
print $thpic[1]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344842/set-multiply-parameters-in-a-for-loop/19344857#comment28659794_19344842 … you aren't proposing any improvement.

Answer (score 1):

you should use any array for this task

```
$thpic = array();
for($i=0;$i<=14;$i++)
{
    $thpic[$i] = "thpic_dummy";
}

echo $thpic[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable-variables to achieve what you want:

```
for($i=0;$i<=14;$i++)
{
    $variable  = 'thpic' . $i;
    $$variable = "thpic_dummy";
}
```

You can read more about these in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Alternatively, you can use the syntax: `${"thpic" . $i} = "thpic_dummy";`